# Oracle SQL: Return a set without duplicates

Tags: oracle

Using the following query is working for me except that I need to only return one result for each `TPHONE.ID`.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to check two tables for three date fields (two in the `TPHONE` table and one in the `TPHONEREQUEST` table and return the `TPHONE.ID` of any place where I find dates within a particular range. However, if more than one entry in either table has one or more of the dates within the date range I'd still only want to return the `TPHONE.ID` once.

```
SELECT 
   TPHONE.ID,
   TPHONE.LOCATIONID,
   TPHONE.DLASTCHANGED,
   TPHONE.D02,
   TPHONEREQUEST.D03
FROM
   TPHONE, TPHONEREQUEST
WHERE
   TPHONE.ID = TPHONEREQUEST.DEVICEID
   AND TPHONE.ID IN
   (
   SELECT
      TPHONE.ID
   FROM
      TPHONE
   WHERE
      TPHONE.DLASTCHANGED >= '7/1/2019' AND TPHONE.DLASTCHANGED < '10/1/2019'
      OR TPHONE.D02 >= '7/1/2019' AND TPHONE.D02 < '10/1/2019'
      OR TPHONEREQUEST.D03 >= '7/1/2019' AND TPHONEREQUEST.D03 < '10/1/2019'
   )
ORDER BY
   TPHONE.LOCATIONID, TPHONE.ID
```

Comment: But why are you selecting  `TPHONEREQUEST.D03`? Which phone request would you show if no or multiple phone requests match the date range?

Comment: Side notes: **(1)** You are using a join syntax that was made redundant in standard SQL in 1992! Please use explicit joins (`from tphone inner join  tphonerequest on ...`). **(2)** You are relying on Oracle recognizing your dates, which is in no way guaranteed to happen. You depend on database session settings. Use date literals instead (e.g. `date '2019-01-07'` or `date '2019-07-01'`, I don't even know what it is). **(3)** You can use table aliases to enhance readability. **(4)** When mixing `AND` and `OR` you should use parentheses for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and filter with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT p.ID,
FROM
    TPHONE p
    INNER JOIN TPHONEREQUEST t ON p.ID = r.DEVICEID
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING
    MAX(
        CASE WHEN 
            (
                p.DLASTCHANGED >= TO_DATE('07/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
                AND p.DLASTCHANGED < TO_DATE('10/1/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
            ) OR (
                p.D02 >= TO_DATE('07/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
                AND p.D02 < TO_DATE('10/1/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
            ) OR (
                r.D03 >= TO_DATE('07/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
                AND r.D03 < TO_DATE('10/1/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
            )
        THEN 1
        END
    ) = 1
```

Notes:

- this returns only `TPHONE.ID`, since this seems to be what you are looking for; if you want more columns, then you can add them to the `SELECT` clause and to the `GROUP BY` clause (beware that this might change the grouping condition though, if these columns are not functionnaly dependant on `TPHONE.ID`)
- I used table aliases to shorten the query
- I used `TO_DATE()` to generate proper dates instead of relying on the default format of the database (which may change across databses and sessions). There is an assumption here that the format of your dates is `DD/MM/YYYY` (it could also be `MM/DD/YYYY`)

Answer (score 1):

You could use ROW_NUMBER to enumerate the rows with the same ID and then select only the first instance:

```
SELECT TPHONE.ID,
       TPHONE.LOCATIONID,
       TPHONE.DLASTCHANGED,
       TPHONE.D02,
       TPHONEREQUEST.D03
FROM (
         SELECT TPHONE.ID,
                TPHONE.LOCATIONID,
                TPHONE.DLASTCHANGED,
                TPHONE.D02,
                TPHONEREQUEST.D03,
                ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY TPHONE.ID ORDER BY TPHONE.ID) as RN
         FROM TPHONE,
              TPHONEREQUEST
         WHERE TPHONE.ID = TPHONEREQUEST.DEVICEID
           AND TPHONE.ID IN
               (
                   SELECT TPHONE.ID
                   FROM TPHONE
                   WHERE TPHONE.DLASTCHANGED >= '7/1/2019' AND TPHONE.DLASTCHANGED < '10/1/2019'
                      OR TPHONE.D02 >= '7/1/2019' AND TPHONE.D02 < '10/1/2019'
                      OR TPHONEREQUEST.D03 >= '7/1/2019' AND TPHONEREQUEST.D03 < '10/1/2019'
               )
         ORDER BY TPHONE.LOCATIONID, TPHONE.ID
     )
WHERE RN = 1
```